# Querying BaseX using .xqj queries

Tags: marklogic, basex

Can we use .xqj files for querying BaseX as we use .xqy to query xml in Marklogic?
I don't think in baseX .xqy can be used to query.

Answer (score 1):

`xqy` is a valid XQuery file extension both in BaseX and in MarkLogic. You can additionally use `xq`, `xqm`, `xql`, `xqu` and `xquery` (but not `xqj`; see http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Extensions#Suffixes).

If you address and run a query file via the BaseX command-line interface or visual frontend, however, the file extension does not matter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just want to confirm one thing, we can use .xqy fie(previously written for marklogic), in basex..right? no need of conversion right?

Comment: With extreme care in your xquery code to only use standard & supported calls, you could theoretically use one .xqy file in both basex and MarkLogic.  However, of course if you use any proprietary calls they won't work on the other platform.

Comment: As Sam indicated, the major question is if your query contains pure XQuery 3.1. If it contains MarkLogic specific code, it will not work with BaseX.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, MarkLogic supports these extensions out of the box: `xqy,xqe,xq,xquery`. You can add `.xqj` as well, by adding the extension to the Mimetypes table in the Admin UI.

HTH!